# Expected Value of Intersection of two Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Ok the problem is as follows: (I am currently studying for my first actuary exam so this isn't a specific hw question! Just trying to figure it out!)

A and B will take the same 10-question exam.

Each exam question will be answered correctly by A with probability $0.7$, independently of her results on other questions.

Each exam question will be answered correctly by B with prob. $0.4$, independently of results on other questions and A.

a. Find the expected number of questions that are answered correctly by both A and B.

Ok... I started this by first calculating

$$\mathbb E[A] = \sum_{i=1}^{10} i{10 \choose i}(0.7)^i (1-0.7)^{10-i}$$ -so, treating this as a binomial random variable

I did this same thing for E[B]. I got the following results:

E[A] = 7

E[B] = 3.570018...

Now... to get the expected number of questions answered correctly by both A and B I assumed that this must be the intersection of the probability that A and B will answer the same questions correctly. Since they are independent I did

E[A*B] = ∑i^2*(10 choose i)(.7)^i*(.4)^i*(1-.7)^(10-i)*(1-.4)^(10-i) for i=1,2,...,10

This answer gives me approximately 2.15, when the correct solutions is 2.8 according to the text book

Other thoughts I have had are:

-multiply only by i, instead of i^2 since this would provide the intersection of p(A) * p(B) (This makes more sense to me in reasoning), however this value would be smaller than 2.15... and therefor cannot be the correct either!

Calculate E[A], then for each E[A=i], calculate E[B] i from 1 up to that value of i and then sum. i.e= If A gets 4 questions right, calculate the probability that B gets 1 of those questions right, 2 of those questions right, 3 of those questions right, all of the same questions right. I haven't tried this on paper yet because I'm not really sure how to set it up?

A little guidance, or if someone could enlighten me to where I am going wrong would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: E(X) for binomial random variable X = n*p. So E(B) must be = 10*0.4 = 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, each question is an independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trial; that is, from each examinee's perspective, the outcome is either "correct" or "incorrect."  So the probability that a given question on the test is answered correctly by **both** A and B is simply the product of the individual probabilities of each answering correctly; i.e., $(0.7)(0.4) = 0.28 = p$.  Then the probability distribution for the number of questions that both examinees got correct is Binomial with parameters $n = 10$ and $p = 0.28$.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that both A and B correctly answer a particular question is $0.7\times0.4=0.28$, since those events are independent.  So you have $n=10$ trials with probability $p=0.28$ of success on each trial.  The expected value of a $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable is $np$, so in this case that is $10\times0.28$.

You have $(1-0.7)(1-0.4)$ where you need $1-((0.7)(0.4))$.

You refer to the "intersection of two binomial random variables" and the "intersection of probabilities".  But one takes intersections of *events*, not of random variables or numbers.